# Migration from homemade models to core data models: setter/getter issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, setter

I'm beginning to learn how use Core Data for my app, and I have a question about setter and getter with `NSManagedObject`.

In my old models I was using this syntax to declare attributes :

```
@interface MyModel : NSObject 
{
    MyAttributeOfClass *_myAttributeOfClass
}

- (void)setMyAttributeOfClass:(MyAttributeOfClass *)anAttributeOfClass;
- (MyAttributeOfClass *)myAttributeOfClass;
```

I know, I could use `@synthesize` for doing this stuff. But if I use `@synthesize` with a public attribute like :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyAttributeOfClass *myAttributeOfClass;
```

A developer could bypass my setter and directly set a value for `myAttributeOfClass` by doing this: `myAttributeOfClass = bar;`. I don't want to allow this behaviour because I use a setter to perform an action. If this action is not done, my class will no longer work correctly.

So, now I am migrating my old model to Core Data model subclassed from `NSManagedObject`.

But when I generate classes from my data model, the attributes are declared this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyAttribute *myAttribute;
```

So, a developer can set a value for this attribute without calling a setter: myAttribute = bar; and I would like forbid it.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes of Core Data managed objects are not backed-up by instance variables. An attribute can be set using the property syntax:

```
object.myAttribute = bar;
```

or with Key-Value Coding:

```
[object setValue:bar forKey:@"myAttribute"];
```

and in both cases the setter method

```
-(void)setMyAttribute:(MyAttribute *)value;
```

is called. Setter and getter method are usually created dynamically at runtime, but you
can provide your own explicit setter and/or getter method.

However, it is possible to bypass the setter by calling the "primitive" accessor methods:

```
[object setPrimitiveValue:bar forKey:@"myAttribute"];
```

This is what a custom setter method would use, but anybody can call the primitive accessor,
there is no way to inhibit that.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't think that object.myAtteibute = bar called my custom setter. Thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

My approach when I want to have a private setter is to have this in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString*  myProperty;
```

And then in the .m file add:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* myProperty;
@end
```

Externally the property is read-only, but by defining a private category in the implementation file, the property is readwrite within the implementation.

Comment: Note that this does still allow setPrimitiveValue and setValue:forKey:, but, for that matter, Objective-C never really has private methods since everything can be found through reflection.